# A function, which takes a list of strings - each element is a book. The output of this function is a 2D NumPy array of books by counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Write a function, featurize, which takes a list of strings as its lone **input argument: each element is a string with the contents of an entire book. The output of this function is a 2D NumPy array of counts, where the rows are the documents/books (i.e., one row per element!) and the columns are the counts for all the words in the global vocabulary.**

For instance, if I pass a two-string list to featurize that collectively have 50 unique words between the two strings, the output matrix should have shape (2, 50): the first row will be the respective counts of the words in that document, and same with the second row.

The rows (documents) should be in the same ordering as they're given in the function's argument list, and the columns (words) should be in increasing lexicographic order (aka alphabetic order). You are welcome to use your function from Part B, and from Part E (Part E's function would be particularly useful here, since that pretty much does all the heavy lifting; you'd just need to convert that dictionary to a matrix).

```
import numpy as np
def featurize (a):
    vocab = ()
    for i in a:
        counts = word_counts(i)
        vocab.extend(counts)
    return (np.shape(vocab))
```

Comment: This also sounds like homework. Isn't the point for you to try to figure out how to do it on your own? That's how you learn to program.

Comment: '''def featurize(stringlist):
string1 = []
print(string1.count(unique_words))



string2 = string2.count(books)
print(string2)''''

Comment: Put it in the question, not a comment.

Comment: I would love to be able to but my professor literally gives no notes or material to learn from. Just really hard homework.

Comment: I have completed parts B and E correctly.

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all. `string1` is an empty list, what do you expect `string1.count(...)` to count?

Comment: Why doesn't the function use `stringlist`?

Comment: Where is your numpy array?

Comment: How about this attempt. I am actually trying.

Answer (score 0):

Homework is a chance to experiment. Keep at it.

In this type of problem, you likely to be confused by getting the types correct.  You can look at using [type hints](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html), or just be very careful about your naming your variables.  For example, you have `def featurize(a)` and probably want something like `def create_table_of_books_by_wordcount(list_of_books)`.

The second item is that you probably want to look at the Counter class in Python.  You can use `split` to break up the book into words, and `Counter` to count them.  Other function you should look at are `sum(alist)` and `sort` with the `key` argument.

It may seem like a lot, but this problem is just a bunch of little problems.

Good luck!  Keep hacking!  Keep notes!